# Getting javascript to pull array value from hidden input?

Tags: javascript

How can I get the array value from a hidden input field and be able to grab the elements I need?

```
<input type="hidden" name="digital_object[prdcls][0][prdcl_links][0][_resolved]" id="digital_object[prdcls][0][prdcl_links][0][_resolved]" value="{&quot;id&quot;:&quot;/prdcl_titles/1&quot;,&quot;title&quot;:&quot;test (test)&quot;,&quot;primary_type&quot;:&quot;prdcl_title&quot;,&quot;types&quot;:[&quot;prdcl_title&quot;],&quot;json&quot;:&quot;{\&quot;lock_version\&quot;:0,\&quot;title\&quot;:\&quot;test (test)\&quot;,\&quot;publication\&quot;:\&quot;test\&quot;,\&quot;publisher\&quot;:\&quot;test\&quot;,\&quot;created_by\&quot;:\&quot;admin\&quot;,\&quot;last_modified_by\&quot;:\&quot;admin\&quot;,\&quot;create_time\&quot;:\&quot;2016-06-07T13:20:46Z\&quot;,\&quot;system_mtime\&quot;:\&quot;2016-06-07T13:20:46Z\&quot;,\&quot;user_mtime\&quot;:\&quot;2016-06-07T13:20:46Z\&quot;,\&quot;jsonmodel_type\&quot;:\&quot;prdcl_title\&quot;,\&quot;uri\&quot;:\&quot;/prdcl_titles/1\&quot;}&quot;,&quot;suppressed&quot;:false,&quot;publish&quot;:false,&quot;system_generated&quot;:false,&quot;repository&quot;:&quot;global&quot;,&quot;created_by&quot;:&quot;admin&quot;,&quot;last_modified_by&quot;:&quot;admin&quot;,&quot;user_mtime&quot;:&quot;2016-06-07T13:20:46Z&quot;,&quot;system_mtime&quot;:&quot;2016-06-07T13:20:46Z&quot;,&quot;create_time&quot;:&quot;2016-06-07T13:20:46Z&quot;,&quot;uri&quot;:&quot;/prdcl_titles/1&quot;,&quot;jsonmodel_type&quot;:&quot;prdcl_title&quot;}">
```

When I run this I get 'undefined' for valp.
I also have the issue where the function prdcl_link is not executing on the hidden field being created or changed.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("#digital_object[prdcls][0][prdcl_links][0][_resolved]").on('keyup change', prdcl_link);
    $("#digital_object_prdcls__0__volume_num_").on('keyup change', prdcl_link);
    $("#digital_object_prdcls__0__issue_num_").on('keyup change', prdcl_link);

    function prdcl_link(){
        var valp = {};
        valp = $("#digital_object[prdcls][0][prdcl_links][0][_resolved]").val();
        console.log(valp);
        var valv = $("#digital_object_prdcls__0__volume_num_").val();
        var vali = $("#digital_object_prdcls__0__issue_num_").val();

        var res;
        var pub;
        var vol;
        var iss;

        if (valp!=""){
            pub = valp['json']['publication'];
            res = pub;
            if (valv!=""){
                vol = " - Volume " + valv;
                res = res.concat(vol);
            }
            if (vali!=""){
                if (valv!=""){
                    iss = ", Issue " + vali;
                }
                else {
                    iss = " - Issue " + vali;
                }
                res = res.concat(iss);
            }
        }


        $("#digital_object_title_").val(res);
   };
});
```

Comment: The value of an input element is a string, and it can't be accessed like you are trying. But how on earth did you end up with a monstrosity like that in the first place?

Comment: I only had a partial hand in that string (being the data in it).  I am writing a plugin for some open source software.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value of the input seems to be JSON format, but HTML encoded. First you need to decode the string. Underscore have en [`unescape`](http://underscorejs.org/#unescape) function, or you can search to find other ways to do it.

Then you can use [`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) to convert it to a javaScript object. But you have an error, so it can't be parsed. There are some extra quotes around an object named 'json'

```
...,"json":"{...}",...
```

If you didn't have the quotes around the brackets, it would be valid. What I think happened here is the 'json' object got converted to JSON format (a string) first. Then this string was part of another object, which also got converted to JSON. Now it's impossible to distinguish which quotes is part of what.